# PERVASIVE - SQL Double - Date REquests

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

in my Table column DeliveryDate datatype is "DOUBLE" not Date

How can I select the following example

SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE DeliveryDate>='01.01.2021'

Can I Convert CURRENTDATE() to a DOUBLE Value?

thx

Comment: How is the date stored in the DOUBLE?  I've seen several methods of storing dates over the years. Once you've figured out how it's stored, you can write a method of converting the value you want to search for.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that no, you can't just CONVERT a DATE to DOUBLE.  If you execute:

```
select convert(CURDATE(), sql_double)
```

You will get an error.  This is because `CURDATE` returns a date in the form MM\DD\YYYY.  Because of the slashes, the conversion to Double fails.
You can do something like this:

> select convert(
> concat(
> DatePart(year,curdate())
> , concat(right(concat('00', DatePart(month, curdate())),2)
> , right(concat('00', DatePart(day, curdate())),2))), sql_double)

But that assumes the DOUBLE is just a YYYYMMDD concatenation of the DATE value.

You need to determine what format your DOUBLE field is and adjust the algorithm to fit your needs.